# How much life left in my Patriot P210 512GB SSD?

Tags: ssd

I noticed that within 2 month, 3 terabytes of data has been written on my SSD. I have just windows and few basic software installed on my SSD. Games are installed on my hard drive. Is this normal for my Patriot P210 SSD?

Edit:
[My SSD stats by Crystal Disk Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j94ih.png)

Update: I think this is normal because 1.5 TB is written average so I think an SSD has 150TBW life and if 1.5 is TBW per month then it will take 100 months to reach 150 TBW.

Comment: That seems pretty high. I wonder if there were some "false starts" during setup.  I also imagine that if you are using Bitlocker that would have taken 500 gigs of that 3tb to encrypt by itself.  I'd keep an eye on it, and see if that figure stays at 1.5tb per month or if it decreases to something more nominal before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Bitlocker is turned off. How can I reduce this number? Also I just searched about whats a 'false start' and no there is no false start. My PC boots normally.

Comment: Is your pagefile or hibernate file on the SSD? If you're running low on RAM and Windows starts to page, then the pagefile will bloat until it's able to dispose once the RAM usage reduces. Or if you're hibernating, you'll be writing the system state out to the hibernate file which lives in the root of C:\ by default.

Comment: @spikey_richie I think 1.5 TBW per month is normal. I just add an update in description. What do you say?

Comment: I would still consider moving your pagefile to a different drive, or adding more RAM so you're not paging so often.

Comment: @I have 32 gb of memory installed. I will try to move pagefile to another drive too.

Comment: 100 months is over 8 years, you'll probably replace the disk or the whole machine long before that...

Comment: @Aganju Yeah, I was worried initially but realized now that this TBW is not bad.